# When sorting row, how to swap columns along in multidimensional-array?

Tags: java, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an array[x][y]

```
4 2 0 3 1 
t o b e o 
r n o t t 
o b e x x
```

How can i sort only the for row but move the column with the row.
The result have to be

```
0 1 2 3 4
b o o e t
o t n t r
e x b x o
```

i tried with

```
for (char[] innerArray : grid) {
    Arrays.sort(innerArray);
}
```

but it sorts all rows.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  We are a question-and-answer site, not a coders-for-hire service. Please narrow your question down to a specific coding problem that would be on-topic for this site.  See: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) and [How to ask a good question when I'm not sure what I'm looking for?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262527/how-to-ask-a-good-question-when-im-not-sure-what-im-looking-for)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution for Your problem. this Algorithme can do exactly what you mention above.

```
Integer[][] arr = new Integer[4][4];
        arr[0][0] = 4;
        arr[0][1] = 3;
        arr[0][2] = 1;
        arr[0][3] = 2;

        arr[1][0] = 6;
        arr[1][1] = 4;
        arr[1][2] = 9;
        arr[1][3] = 2;

        arr[2][0] = 9;
        arr[2][1] = 7;
        arr[2][2] = 5;
        arr[2][3] = 4;

        arr[3][0] = 11;
        arr[3][1] = 33;
        arr[3][2] = 6;
        arr[3][3] = 8;

for (int i = 0; i < arr[0].length; i++) {
    for (int j = i+1; j < arr[0].length; j++) { 
        if (arr[0][i] > arr[0][j]) {    
            for (int k = 0; k < arr.length; k++) {
                int temp = arr[k][i];
                arr[k][i] = arr[k][j];
                arr[k][j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

> To print out the Array for testing purpose .

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < arr[0].length; j++) {
        if (arr[i][j] > 9) {
            System.out.print(arr[i][j]+"  ");
        }else{
            System.out.print(arr[i][j]+"   ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

> This is an exemple of the above.

**before Sorting**

```
4   3   1   2   
6   4   9   2   
9   7   5   4   
11  33  6   8
```

**After Sorting**

```
1   2   3   4   
9   2   4   6   
5   4   7   9   
6   8   33  11
```

I hope that this solution meet your requirements.

Comment: Simply and straight to the point, albeit inefficient. Very nice!